# TFS Build is building multiple configurations despite choosing Release

Tags: tfsbuild

When i build (TFS 2012) my 4 solutions with Configurations to build = Any CPU|Release it is building All of them as Release, 2 of them as Debug | Mixed Platforms, and one of them as Debug | Any CPU.

If i set it to release i would like it to only do the release build. Could anyone give me some insight into why it is also doing some debug builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Have you specified multiple configurations to build in the Build Configuration? In the build configuration, goto the `Process` tab, then `Items to Build` -> `Configurations to Build`.
- Secondly, review your Solution Configurations.  You can get to this through the `Build` menu within Visual Studio then `Configuration Manager`.  Here you can edit how the projects are supposed to build given a specified solution configuration.

**Update**

- If you have customised the build process template then try stripping this back to the Default one and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer this. I have checked the solution configuration and it all looks good. There is also only one setting set in the 'configurations to build' option this is set to Release | Any CPU.

Comment: Can you upload the build log to pastebin for me to take a look at?

Comment: Sure, it's built using "Verbose" http://pastebin.com/zz6Lc94j

Comment: Can you point me to line numbers where you think it is doing something wrong?  I've had a scan, but can't see a great deal wrong.  thanks

Comment: I agree, i couldn't see anything wrong from the log either. But the summary is saying that of my 4 solutions defined in "items to build" some of them are getting built in Debug | Mixed and Debug | Any CPU despite me specifying it to build in Release only.

Comment: Where's the summary?  I don't see it in the pastebin

Comment: It's a different output, I have added it here, although it doesnt say much. http://pastebin.com/Q3yUQjBH

Comment: OK - I think i'm almost out of ideas.  One final thing, can you check that the serialised build configuration in the TFS database is correct.  Go to tbl_BuildDefinition in the collection database and look at the column ProcessParameters.

Comment: Found the problem, although not yet the solution, i have a heavily modified BuildProcessTemplate and it seems to be the issue, it must do something in there that i have deleted from the original template.